# Event lost after using colorbox in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, colorbox

I have a problem when using colorbox. It worked fine, but after closing the popup window and doing any event using linkbutton that does a postback the event doesn't work and open new window contains last popup window.

Thanks Advanced,

Mahmoud Elsayed Abd Elaty

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 1):

Try re-initializing the colorbox plugin once your postback has completed, e.g.:

```
$.get("foo.html", function (html) {
    $("#myDiv").html(html);
    $("#myDiv .someElement").colorbox();
});
```

Comment: i tried it and doesn't work also .any linkbuttons lost event after postback

Comment: Can you please post some code and markup, it's really hard to guess what the problem is.

Comment: <a class="ajax"  href="" id="editshippaddress" runat="server">Edit</a><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn_setdefaultshipp" runat="server" OnClick="lnkbtn_setdefaultshipp_click">Set Default</asp:LinkButton> after click first on work fine. then after click 'set default address' it's open a new window not popup containing the previous popup window.it lost the event after postback of colorbox.